# Joining rows and columns in SQL

Tags: sql, join, left-join, distinct, case-when

Current Result:

```
ID | Item      | Red | Green | Blue | Yellow
03   balloon      1      0       0      0
03   balloon      0      1       0      0
03   balloon      1      0       0      1
24   ribbon       0      0       1      0
24   ribbon       0      1       0      0
24   ribbon       0      0       0      1
24   ribbon       1      0       0      0
```

Desired Result:

```
ID | Item      | Red | Green | Blue | Yellow
03   balloon      1      1       0      1
24   ribbon       1      1       1      1
```

I don't want them to be repeated like it does in my current result.

This is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tb1.ID
      , tb1.Item
      , (CASE WHEN tb2.color = 'Red' THEN 1 END) AS 'Red'
      , (CASE WHEN tb2.color = 'Green' THEN 1 END) AS 'Green'
      , (CASE WHEN tb2.color = 'Blue' THEN 1 END) AS 'Blue'
      , (CASE WHEN tb2.color = 'Yellow' THEN 1 END) AS 'Yellow'
FROM #table1 tb1
LEFT JOIN #table2 tb2 ON tb1.ID = tb2.ID
```

I have tried without distinct too and I don't know how to alter to get to make it look like the desired result.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code in table format. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregation:

```
SELECT tb1.ID, tb1.Item
      MAX(CASE WHEN tb2.color = 'Red' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Red,
      MAX(CASE WHEN tb2.color = 'Green' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Green,
      MAX(CASE WHEN tb2.color = 'Blue' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Blue,
      MAX(CASE WHEN tb2.color = 'Yellow' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Yellow
FROM #table1 tb1 LEFT JOIN
     #table2 tb2 
     ON tb1.ID = tb2.ID 
GROUP BY tbl1.ID;
```

Note that your current result should be returning `NULL` rather than `0`.  I added `ELSE 0`, so you explicitly get `0`.

Also, don't use single quotes for column aliases.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.